# Float left, then float right when line breaks

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two banner ads, one on the far left side of the page and one on the far right with a float:right.

```
<div id="sponsers">
<span class="banner1">
   <img src='url' />
   </span>
   <span class="banner2" style='float: right;'>
   <img src='url' />
   </span>
</div>
```

I like how this looks, but when the browser width is narrowed and the second banner breaks to a new line, the two banners overlap in an odd looking way. ----*_*_

I would like the second banner to float left when a line break occurs so the banners stack one directly above the other.

How can I accomplish this?

(Unfortunately I cannot upload an image with out 10 reputation)

Comment: First you need to determine at what resolution(screen width) the two images break at. Then use a media query to make banner2 float right anytime below that breakpoint.

Answer (score 2):

You can use media queries for this

HTML

```
<div id="sponsers">
<span class="banner1 banner"><img src='url' /></span>
<span class="banner2 banner"><img src='url' /></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#sponsers{
 /* do whatever */
}

.banner{
    width: 400px;
    height: 30px;
    color: #f3f3f3;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: block;
}

.banner1{
    float: left;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 680px) {
.banner2{
    float: left;

}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 681px) {
.banner2{
    float: right;

}
}
```

JSFiddle Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/vLWaA/

*Note, update your desired breakpoints accordingly.  Currently set to 680px.

Answer (score 1):

You'll use a media query to do this. Your breakpoint should be a max-width equal to the total width of your two images, plus any padding you'd like to establish between them. In my example, this is 800px (two 400px images).

Demo: http://codepen.io/etjossem/pen/cIJrv

HTML

```
<div class="first-banner">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x150">
</div>
<div class="second-banner">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x150">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.first-banner {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}

.second-banner {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .second-banner, .first-banner {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .second-banner {
    float: left;
  }
}
```